# Call function/method of the target fragment when navigated using Fragment Navigation (nav graph)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

currently my app has one activity with two fragments, One is `HomeFragment`and the other is `SearchFragment`. I am using Fragment Navigation to navigate between Fragments.

In the `SearchFragment`, I am asking the user to provide the value that he/she wants to search. Once done, I want the app to navigate back to `HomeFragment` and perform the search. For that purpose, I created an Interface and build a method in `SearchFragment` called `addListener()`to set that listener.

Not to navigate from HomeFragment to SearchFragment I am using following line:

```
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_to_search_fragment, bundle)
```

This gives me no option to call a method of SearchFragment as I have no instance of that. Can anyone here help me out on this?

How to get the instance or call a method, it would be a big help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Navigation library, you can pass the query as an argument to `HomeFragment`. For this, add an argument to `HomeFragment` in the nav graph with a default value `null`. Use that query argument in `HomeFragment` to display the appropriate data.

In the `SearchFragment`, when user types the query and hits Search, instead of going back to `HomeFragment` via `navigateUp()` or `popBackStack()` you can move forward to `HomeFragment` via an action. And while going from `SearchFragment` to `HomeFragment`, remember to pop these two out of the back stack first (use `popUpTo` attribute in your nav graph for this) so that you have only `HomeFragment` in the back stack at the end.

**Another approach:** Probably a more straightforward way will be to use the Fragment Result API to send data from one fragment to another. You can refer [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result) for understanding the usage.

Comment: But don't you think it will remove the state of  ````HomeFragment````? Right now I am navigating back to the ````HomeFragment```` by manually calling the ````onBackPressed()````

Comment: What data do you have in `HomeFragment` that you refer to as "state"?

Comment: It's a web browser application containing a webview, which could have some page loaded in it already

Comment: I have edited the answer to add another approach. Try that out, if you face any trouble, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MutableLiveData` and store data in a LiveData in your ViewModel or Activity as bellow:

Add this line to your `Module-level` build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
}
```

define the variable in your ViewModel:

```
val searchQuery: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

update the data when user provides the value:

```
viewModel.searchQuery.postValue(query)
```

And you can use the value in your homeFragment:

```
viewModel.searchQuery.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { query: String ->
    // Do whatever you want with query
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also include `Navigation Safe Args`.
then in nav_graph carry out an action from `SearchFragment` to `HomeFragment`,
and also in `nav_graph` set an argument for `HomeFragment` with type String and default value `null` or just `""`.

Then inside the send command in `SearchFragment` you write the following:

```
val action = SearchFragmentDirection.actionSearchFragmentToHomeFragment(EditText.text.toSrting)
findNavController.navigate(action)
```

you accept data in `HomeFragment`, for this you create globally
an instance of your HomeFragmentArgs:

```
private val args: HomeFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

And transfer logic from SearchFragment to HomeFragment
and insert this argument

and paste this argument(args) where you make a request or call

You can learn more about Safe Args here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Comment: I am navigating to ````SearchFragment```` via action and then coming back by manually calling ````onBackPressed()```` in ````SearchFragment```` in this way, new instance of ````HomeFragment```` is not created.